# django: smart-select ChainedForeignKey / chained dropdown in admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, m2m, django-smart-selects

Hej! :)

I have 5 models which are connected hierarchical with each other.
Section -> division -> group -> class -> wz

one section can have multiple divisions, but one division can only have one section (and so on). Therefor I have ForeignKeys set:

```
# models.py
class NaceSection(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=1, unique=True)
    description_english = models.CharField(max_length=500)


class NaceDivision(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=2, unique=True)
    nace_section = models.ForeignKey(NaceSection, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="nace_section")
    description_english = models.CharField(max_length=500)


class NaceGroup(models.Model):
    nace_division = models.ForeignKey(NaceDivision, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="nace_division")
    code = models.CharField(max_length=4, unique=True)
    description_english = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

I than have a model where all those are integrated as M2M fields with a dropdown option.
My goal is to only get the divisions which are in the already selected section in the admin area. (and so on)

I tried smart-select ChainedForeignKey:

```
# models.py

class Institution(models.Model):
    nace_sections = models.ManyToManyField(
        NaceSection,
        related_name="nace_sections"
    )
    nace_divisions = ChainedForeignKey(
        NaceDivision,
        chained_field="nace_sections",
        chained_model_field='nace_sections',
        blank=True,
    )
     nace_group = ChainedForeignKey(
        NaceGroup,
        chained_field="nace_divisions",
        chained_model_field='nace_divisions',
        blank=True,
    )
```

The organisation and dropdown in the admin area do not change at all and my view with a table of all my results tells me `('42S22', "[42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'nace_divisions_id'. (207) (SQLExecDirectW)")`

With the ChainedManyToManyField nothing at all happens. Does anybody know what's going wrong?
Any help appreciated! :)

Comment: Does your error not lie in using `nace_divisions` for your chained_field instead of `nace_division`

Comment: No. If I change it to nace_section and nace_division the dropdown shows all options in the admin and when saving the error `('42S22', "[42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'nace_divisions_id'. (207) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")` occurse.

Answer (score 0):

nace_sections is specified as models.ManyToManyField in your code

1.Change from ManyToManyField to ForeignKey.

2.Rename  chained_model_field values

-->nace_sections to nace_section
-->nace_divisions to nace_division

```
class Institution(models.Model):
nace_sections = models.ForeignKey(
    NaceSection,
    related_name="nace_sections"
    , on_delete=models.CASCADE
)
nace_divisions = ChainedForeignKey(
    NaceDivision,
    chained_field="nace_sections",
    chained_model_field='nace_section',
    blank=True,
)
nace_group = ChainedForeignKey(
    NaceGroup,
    chained_field="nace_divisions",
    chained_model_field='nace_division',
    blank=True,
)
```

Comment: I still get the error, that nace_sections_id, nace_divisions_id and so on not exist.

Comment: Can you post your exact error message? In which scenario it appears like during migration or  while opening admin page?

Comment: Also have u changed this  :                                                                                        
    chained_model_field='nace_sections'                                                               
    ###Remove 's' here ####
   chained_model_field='nace_section',                                                                                    
                                                                                        
    chained_model_field='nace_divisions',    
    ### Remove 's' here ####
    chained_model_field='nace_division',

Comment: `('42S22', "[42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'nace_sections_id'. (207) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'nace_divisions_id'. (207); [42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'nace_groups_id'. (207);`

Comment: and yes I removed the 's'.